# kubernetes job does not terminate

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have next kubernetes cronjob specification:

```yaml
          containers:
          - args:
            - -c
            - |
              export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8 ;
              echo "Exporting addresses" ;
              sqlplus bta/$ORACLE_PASSWORD@//10.203.0.34/bta @adm_address_export.sql > /dev/null ;
              if [[ ! -f address.tsv ]]; echo 'File "address.tsv" is not there, aborting.'; echo $? ; then exit 0; fi ;
              echo "Ready to import addresses" ;
```

I want this job to fail if address.tsv is not created by command before. But for some reason it fails also if file exist.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: then should follow directly after if [[..]]

Comment: Put a shebang at your shell code and paste it at https://shellcheck,net

Comment: @RamanSailopal your answer worked thank you!

Comment: @Jetchisel thanks for help. That did only check syntax, what appeared to be ok.

Comment: `help if` should print the syntax for the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement is incorrect in that then needs to follow if [[ ... ]] and so:

```
if [[ ! -f address.tsv ]]; then echo 'File "address.tsv" is not there, aborting.'; echo $? ; exit 0; fi
```